# SharePoint 2013 App domain/subdomain

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

I have a question regarding **subdomain** usage when configuring a **SharePoint App domain**. If I have a farm at `spfarm.companyname.com`, would it be safe to use an app domain of `apps.companyname.com`? This is technically not a subdomain of the `FQDN` that is hosting the SP site.

Any thoughts on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that's Microsoft's recommendation:

> To help improve security, the domain name should not be a subdomain of
>   the domain that hosts the SharePoint sites.

(From the section "Configure the domain names in DNS" in this article:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx)

Comment: Awesome. I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't missing anything because all of the literature I find online stresses not using subdomains for the app domain. I should be fine as long as the app domain isn't a subdomain of the domain hosting the SP site itself...

Comment: Even though the urls "spfarm.companyname.com" and "apps.companyname.com" are not subdomains of each other, they still share a common second level domain which allows for some cookie based attacks.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12412/what-cookie-attacks-are-possible-between-computers-in-related-dns-domains-exa.  Of course, the AppWebs generated by SharePoint would always share a second level domain regardless - not sure what protections, if any, SharePoint provides for AppWebs in that regards.