# SharePoint on Azure - how do you deal with * apps domain without custom domain?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, azure

I do not have a custom domain.

I have an SP with SQL+DC+DNS as a virtual machine on Azure. I added an endpoint on port 80 and my site http://wonderful.cloudapp.net and all other path-based site collections http://wonderful.cloudapp.net/sites/SiteNumber1, etc. are available over the Internet.

**How do you set up an app domain on Azure machine to be available on the Internet without a custom domain and DNS provider?** Would it be e.g. http://apps-6473346.wonderful.cloudapp.net?

DNS Zone on Azure with *.wonderful.cloudapp.net nor apps-ParticularID.wonderful.cloudapp.net do not seem to work. Editing host file on local computer of course fixes the resolution but is not a viable solution.
I am aware of [security concerns](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163726/sharepoint-2013-app-domain-subdomain) and the apps function perfectly on the server itself, but everywhere on the Internet the subdomain is not resolved.

Are there any other solutions? I am not attached to any particular app domain settings. As long as it does not require custom domain and can be resolved over the Internet with *, it would be a solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: there is no way. You need to have your custom domain and then redirect it to e.g. the IP of your Azure VM.